# Euro-Symbol in Plot

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I want my "main" and my "sub" to contain the Euro-Sign "€".
Rstudio is displaying the Euro-Sign perfectly, meanwhile my saved pdf-Plot  is displaying "..." instead of "€".

Can you help me? What am I doing wrong?

Here's a minimal example:

```
Euro <- "\u20AC"

pdf("test.pdf")
plot(1:10,main=paste("Gained money in",Euro,sep=" "), 
xlab="Day",ylab=paste("Money in",Euro,sep=" "))
```

I've already found out that the problem appears to be the pdf-format, because png is working totally fine. Converting it later on to pdf with "convert" in bash is possible, but the actual plot needs the high pdf-resolution.

Thanks!

Comment: try `cairo_pdf`

Comment: AWESOME thanks!!!!!! :-))))

Comment: I suspect this is encoding issue.